# Mutex not acquiring the critical section in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have a piano which plays songs. Each song has an array representative with notes in it.

There are 10 songs. In myTone1, I check which song is being played. And acquire the m mutex. So I don't have songs playing at the same time. So I used the mutex according to flutter documentation, but it's not working. Songs are still playing with each other.

```
void simonPlay (int index, int c) async {

      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: index *  500), () {
        songs.play(c);
      });
  }

  void playSequence(List<int> sequence) async {
    try {
      // critical section with asynchronous code
     for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length ; i++) {

          simonPlay(i,sequence[i]);
      }
  } finally {
    m.release();
    }
    }


  Widget myTone1(Color myColor1,Color myColor2, int myNumber)
  {
    return Expanded(
       child : AbsorbPointer ( absorbing: false,
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(myColor1)),
          onPressed: () async {
              setState(() async {
                switch (myNumber) {
                  case 1:
                    await m.acquire();
                    playSequence(song1);
                    break;
                  case 2:
                    await m.acquire();
                    playSequence(song2);
                    break;

                  case 3:
                    await m.acquire();
                    playSequence(song3);
                    break;

                  //from 3 to 8

                  case 9:
                    await m.acquire();
                    playSequence(song9);
                    break;

                  case 10:
                    await m.acquire();
                    playSequence(song10);

                }

              },
              );
```

Comment: `setState` :  The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. It must not return a future (the callback cannot be `async`), since then it would be unclear when the state was actually being set.

Comment: If I remove async from setState then I can't use await m.aquire();

Comment: How would recommend me to edit it?

Comment: After call `switch` function, you can call `setState` function. for example `switch(){}; setState((){//No need to add anything})`;

Comment: It's not working, can you please elaborate with a complete answer?